# Cant create cocos2d project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

So I am fairly sure everything is all configured right.  So far I have ran a cocos2d project for windows through visual studio.  Now I am trying to do it for android through eclipse with android tools.

So far I have created the project folder with the "cocos new" command
This command seemed to go well except it talked about changing the bundle id on apple devices.

Then I went into "proj.android" and ran "build_native.py".  This I think unfortunately failed.  The console went on for awhile then it talks about "raise exception ...... failed"  after going for about a second.

If I import the project into eclipse it wont build because it cant import cocos. I really have no clue what went wrong just that the console for the "build_native.py" probably had issues.

Is their a way I can copy the console output so you can see what it spit out?

Comment: Why not use Android Studio

Comment: I couldnt find any good tutorials on setting it up there.

Comment: Open cmd, go to proj.android-studio, run `cocos compile -p android --android-studio`. That's it. If no error happens, you will get a android studio project.

Comment: @zen error running command.  Error return 2.

Comment: Post the error outputs.